# What is the other side of a category-indexed multicategory

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, fibration

By a category-indexed multicategory I mean a pseudofunctor from a category C to the 2-category of multicategories. For example, consider the pseudo functor which sends a topological space B to the multicategory multi-linear maps between topological vector bundles over B. I'm interested in the other side of this construction, where you have a "fibration whose fibres are multicategories".

Comment: If the multicategories happen to be representable, hence monoidal categories, then there is the construction of my paper http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/20/18/20-18abs.html .  Perhaps looking at that construction might help come up with a multicategorical version.  I've thought about it occasionally but never written anything down.

Comment: Thanks! I had made a bit of progress by regarding things as a module/profunctor, but I didn't know where to go from there.